# 1, 2, 3... What's next?

Tags: word, pattern

> jxzkgyqhtvfbxoyjsnkwzhcuxogtysfmoivncagkwzjsthiovcbdfrivktyzwbojhuiwtpmltbnxmgnemcsf

Use the title as a free hint. The answer is 9 letters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Analyzing the frequency of the letters, we find that most letters occur 4 times in the sequence. The full frequency is shown below:
>  [image]

> Now notice that there are 8 letters with less than 4 occurances, and 2 with more than 4. Combinations of all the letters with a frequency other than 4 don't yield much progress, but if you look at just the letters with less than 4 occurances, they sum to 9.

> Filtering out all other letters, we get
>  *jxzkgy***q***htvfbxoyjsnkwzhc***u***xogtysfmoivnc***a***gkwzjsthiovcb***d***f***r***ivktyzwbojh***u***iwt***p***m***l***tbnxmgn***e***mcsf*

Giving us the solution:

> **Quadruple**